# How can you access the ADL-SDK from clojure?

Tags: clojure, java-native-interface, swig

I am new to JNI and swig and I'm trying to access AMD's ADL-SDK v6 from clojure but am running into some errors.

```
;; Clojure 1.5.1
=> (com.vnetpublishing.swig.adl.AdapterInfo.)
UnsatisfiedLinkError com.vnetpublishing.swig.adl.adlsdkJNI.new_AdapterInfo()J  com.vnetpublishing.swig.adl.adlsdkJNI.new_AdapterInfo (adlsdkJNI.java:-2)
=> (System/loadLibrary "libatiadlxx")
UnsatisfiedLinkError no libatiadlxx in java.library.path  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary (ClassLoader.java:1886)
```

The swig template is as follows

```
/* File jadl-sdk.i */


%module adlsdk
%{
#include "adl_sdk.h"
%}

%include "adl_defines.h"
%include "adl_structures.h"
%include "adl_sdk.h"
```

The classes were generated with the following command

```
swig -java -package com.vnetpublishing.swig.adl -v -DLINUX -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JADL_PATH}/ADL_SDK/include -outdir ${PACKAGE_PATH} jadl-sdk.i
```

Does anyone know how to get this to function?

-edit-

I have been able to get this to partially function using

```
  (clojure.lang.RT/loadLibrary "atiadlxx")
  (clojure.lang.RT/loadLibrary "jadlsdk")
```

The only problem is the jadlsdk library isn't on the java.library.path , it is inside a jar, and I can't get it to load from leiningen.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The solution was to run the loadLibrary call as part of the static constructor and to install the swig generated wrapper library as a system library (On linux under /usr/lib).

The complete code is available on github at https://github.com/rritoch/WarpCTL/tree/master/extra/JADL-SDK

Once the wrapper library has been installed, and the java wrapper code has been compiled to a jar it can be loaded in the project.clj under :resource-paths

The clojure side code can be accessed @ https://github.com/rritoch/WarpCTL